# font size and font family comparison

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010, itext

i have extracted a PDF using Itextsharp and converted HTML using span tag. i want compare 2 font family font size. i had used http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11454/A-word-wise-HTML-text-compare-and-merge-engine for text comparison . is there any method through which i an differentiate ,match two font family and font size . the final code i am getting like this in HTML .

this is HTML text of one PDF:"<"span style="font-family:ABCDEE+Calibri; "> 
<"span style="font-family:ABCDEE+Calibri; "> steeds prominentere plaats in de organisatie in. Ik 
<"span style="font-family:ABCDEE+Calibri; ">ben zeer <"/span">

this is HTML text of second PDF :<"span style="font-family:ABCDEE+Calibri;"> "<"/span>
<"span style="font-family:ABCDEE+Impact;"> steeds prominentere plaats in de organisatie in. Ik ben zeer <"/span>

here one PDF is having Calibri and second is Impact i want to find difference and highlight if its not matching. can  you please tell me to compare font family and font size. thank you in advance